# Html checkbox displayed with jquery. Need to check if checkbox value changed (checked/unchecked)

Tags: jquery

Here placed all code http://jsfiddle.net/tUukv/

Below is checkbox created/displayed without jquery. If checkbox value changes, then value in `is_checkbox_changed0` changes to `1`. All works.

```
<br>input type='checkbox' without jquery. All works<br>
<table><tr><td>
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_to_update0' name='checkbox_to_update0' class='checkbox_to_update_changed0' value = 'true' >
</td></tr></table>

<table><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="is_checkbox_changed0" id="is_checkbox_changed0" style='width:30px;'>
<script>
$(".checkbox_to_update_changed0").change(function(){
document.getElementById('is_checkbox_changed0').value = 1;
});
</script>
</td></tr></table>
```

But need to display checkbox using jquery

Created such code

```
<br>But with jquery input type='checkbox' does not work<br>

<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#existing_company_error').html("Checkbox <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_to_update' name='checkbox_to_update' class='checkbox_to_update_changed' value = 'true' ><br>");
});
</script>

<div id="existing_company_error"></div>


<table><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="is_checkbox_changed" id="is_checkbox_changed" size="" style='width:30px;'>

<script>
$(".checkbox_to_update_changed").change(function(){
//$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
//$(".checkbox_to_update_changed").on("change", function () {
document.getElementById('is_checkbox_changed').value = 1;
});
</script>

</td></tr></table>
```

If I change checkbox value (either check, or uncheck the checkbox) value in `is_checkbox_changed` must change to `1`. But it does not changes.

Please, advice what need to correct?

**Solution** Oh, I am stupid. `document.getElementById('is_checkbox_changed').value = 1;` must be inside `$(document).ready(function() {`. all works

Comment: doubtless answered elsewhere. Use `$(...).is(':checked')`

Comment: I know about `is(':checked')`. But also need change value if checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the element is created dynamically, use event delegation

```
$(document).on('change', ".checkbox_to_update_changed", function(){
    document.getElementById('is_checkbox_changed').value = 1;
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#existing_company_error').on('change', ".checkbox_to_update_changed", function(){
        document.getElementById('is_checkbox_changed').value = 1;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox_to_update_changed', function(){

});
```

You must use `$(document)` to attach click handlers to dynamically added elements, because `$(document)` always exists, so you can always attach to it. Specifically attaching to an element that does not exist will not work in that case.
Also, it may be a good idea to wrap all `jQuery` code that interacts with the `DOM` with `$(document).ready()`, to ensure everything is loaded before attaching events and such.

(This is my first stack overflow post!)